# How to win in the second scenario (Oasis)?

Tags: i-dig-it-remastered

When you enter the game, the old farmer tells:

> Explore the great underworld. Drill a bit. The core's the limit...
>   literally!

I don't understand what the quest is precisely and how to win the scenario. I now have plenty of money and reached the lowest floor, but nothing happens.

How to win in the second scenario (Oasis)?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure its a quest?  Is it noted somewhere in the game that it is? I don't have the game which is why I ask.

Comment: Yes it is a quest, because the sandbox mode is locked until you win a first time the scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never stated but to win the second map **all you have to do is gather 1.000.000 $** .

[image: you win screenshot]

Its not that hard considering that the **developer heads fetch you 100.000 $**:

[image: developer head]

Also if you like this game I recommend you try [**Super Motherload**](http://store.steampowered.com/app/269110/), its based on the same game but it's more polished.